# Added a Facebook Page Tab via self made app , but the iframe doesn't load the link in the App Settings

Tags: facebook, iframe, tabs

I created an application on Facebook and provided the following settings for page tab and added domains as www.glomania.com and page tab secure url to be also as https://www.glomania.com

My iframe does not loads anything after allowing the app on facebook page but the tab is added correctly. Please guide.

This is the app domain settings: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1xIUf.png

This is the app page tab settings: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tdizk.png

This is the FB page where tab was added
https://www.facebook.com/Akasha-Chaddha-188152831757277/app/828591547345491/

Comment: It loads `https://www.glomania.com/Aditya.php` into the iframe for me. And since that is the only request to your domain I see happening in network panel, it does not seem to be a redirect from your end or anything like that. Facebook does not “guess” arbitrary URLs, so please double-check your app settings. (And make sure the actually got saved, people sometimes just click the button and ignore errors that show up after that.)

Comment: Hey CBroe, Greetings.
Yes I was trying to load the index.php initially as it is called by default but when I changed to Aditya.php then it works .

Any ideas why just https://www.glomania.com/ does not show up anything on the iframe ?
P.S. I have reverted the tab url to https://www.glomania.com/

Comment: Check your browser console, it will tell you. _“Refused to display `https://www.glomania.com/` in a frame because it set `X-Frame-Options` to `sameorigin`.”_

Comment: Yes, It says that, any way around for this. 
Is it glomania.com server that is creating issues?

Comment: Yes, your server/script/system is issuing this header. Since the `/Aditya.php` script did obviously _not_ send this header, you must have done _something_ different, I suppose.

Comment: It was a usual script there, not equally controlled by Magento system,  I will dig more stuff there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Magento has a setting of Allow Magento to run from an IFRAME in System->Configuration

Set it to yes and you can overcome this warning